# XSLT Matching Elements to get another

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm attempting to match elements to return another.

Here is a snippet from the XML. Version = 1.0 and output is text (converting xml to text).

```
<InvestmentHolding>
    <AccountId>900004859</AccountId>
    <InvestmentCode>CASH</InvestmentCode>
    <Exchange>CASH</Exchange>
    <HoldingId>900004859.04</HoldingId>
    <IsCashAccount>false</IsCashAccount>
    <IsSubjectToCGT>false</IsSubjectToCGT>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</InvestmentHolding>
<InvestmentHolding>
    <AccountId>900004859</AccountId>
    <InvestmentCode>ALX</InvestmentCode>
    <Exchange>ASX</Exchange>
    <HoldingId>10983129</HoldingId>
    <IsSMA>
        <Id>900004859.04</Id>
        <Type>Child</Type>
    </IsSMA>
    <IsCashAccount>false</IsCashAccount>
    <IsSubjectToCGT>true</IsSubjectToCGT>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</InvestmentHolding>
<InvestmentHolding>
    <AccountId>900004859</AccountId>
    <InvestmentCode>AMC</InvestmentCode>
    <Exchange>ASX</Exchange>
    <HoldingId>10983138</HoldingId>
    <IsSMA>
        <Id>900004859.04</Id>
        <Type>Child</Type>
    </IsSMA>
    <IsCashAccount>false</IsCashAccount>
    <IsSubjectToCGT>true</IsSubjectToCGT>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</InvestmentHolding>
<InvestmentHolding>
    <AccountId>900004859</AccountId>
    <InvestmentCode>MTS</InvestmentCode>
    <Exchange>ASX</Exchange>
    <HoldingId>10983239</HoldingId>
    <IsSMA>
        <Id>900004859.04</Id>
        <Type>Child</Type>
    </IsSMA>
    <IsCashAccount>false</IsCashAccount>
    <IsSubjectToCGT>true</IsSubjectToCGT>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</InvestmentHolding>
<InvestmentHolding>
    <AccountId>900004859</AccountId>
    <InvestmentCode>NAB</InvestmentCode>
    <Exchange>ASX</Exchange>
    <HoldingId>10983242</HoldingId>
    <IsCashAccount>false</IsCashAccount>
    <IsSubjectToCGT>true</IsSubjectToCGT>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</InvestmentHolding>
<InvestmentHolding>
    <AccountId>900004859</AccountId>
    <InvestmentCode>QBE</InvestmentCode>
    <Exchange>ASX</Exchange>
    <HoldingId>11428205</HoldingId>
    <IsSMA>
        <Id>900004859.04</Id>
        <Type>Child</Type>
    </IsSMA>
    <IsCashAccount>false</IsCashAccount>
    <IsSubjectToCGT>true</IsSubjectToCGT>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</InvestmentHolding>
<InvestmentHolding>
    <AccountId>900004859</AccountId>
    <InvestmentCode>BTFG.SU.6M.MAT</InvestmentCode>
    <Exchange>CASH</Exchange>
    <HoldingId>FIDD.48965</HoldingId>
    <IsTermDeposit>
        <InterestRate>.75</InterestRate>
        <CommencementDate>2020-08-04</CommencementDate>
        <MaturityDate>2021-02-04</MaturityDate>
        <Term>184</Term>
    </IsTermDeposit>
    <IsCashAccount>false</IsCashAccount>
    <IsSubjectToCGT>false</IsSubjectToCGT>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</InvestmentHolding>
<InvestmentHolding>
    <AccountId>900004859</AccountId>
    <InvestmentCode>MPCASH</InvestmentCode>
    <Exchange>CASH</Exchange>
    <HoldingId>900004859.03</HoldingId>
    <IsSMA>
        <Id>900004859.03</Id>
        <Type>Child</Type>
    </IsSMA>
    <IsCashAccount>false</IsCashAccount>
    <IsSubjectToCGT>false</IsSubjectToCGT>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</InvestmentHolding>
<InvestmentHolding>
    <AccountId>900004859</AccountId>
    <InvestmentCode>BGL0008AU</InvestmentCode>
    <Exchange>FND</Exchange>
    <HoldingId>10983051</HoldingId>
    <IsSMA>
        <Id>900004859.03</Id>
        <Type>Child</Type>
    </IsSMA>
    <IsCashAccount>false</IsCashAccount>
    <IsSubjectToCGT>true</IsSubjectToCGT>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</InvestmentHolding>
<InvestmentHolding>
    <AccountId>900004859</AccountId>
    <InvestmentCode>BGL0044AU</InvestmentCode>
    <Exchange>FND</Exchange>
    <HoldingId>10990021</HoldingId>
    <IsSMA>
        <Id>900004859.03</Id>
        <Type>Child</Type>
    </IsSMA>
    <IsCashAccount>false</IsCashAccount>
    <IsSubjectToCGT>true</IsSubjectToCGT>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</InvestmentHolding>
<InvestmentHolding>
    <AccountId>900004859</AccountId>
    <InvestmentCode>BGL0108AU</InvestmentCode>
    <Exchange>FND</Exchange>
    <HoldingId>10990060</HoldingId>
    <IsSMA>
        <Id>900004859.03</Id>
        <Type>Child</Type>
    </IsSMA>
    <IsCashAccount>false</IsCashAccount>
    <IsSubjectToCGT>true</IsSubjectToCGT>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</InvestmentHolding>
<InvestmentHolding>
    <AccountId>900004859</AccountId>
    <InvestmentCode>HOW0098AU</InvestmentCode>
    <Exchange>FND</Exchange>
    <HoldingId>10990043</HoldingId>
    <IsSMA>
        <Id>900004859.03</Id>
        <Type>Child</Type>
    </IsSMA>
    <IsCashAccount>false</IsCashAccount>
    <IsSubjectToCGT>true</IsSubjectToCGT>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</InvestmentHolding>
<InvestmentHolding>
    <AccountId>900004859</AccountId>
    <InvestmentCode>SSB4647AU</InvestmentCode>
    <Exchange>FND</Exchange>
    <HoldingId>10990071</HoldingId>
    <IsSMA>
        <Id>900004859.03</Id>
        <Type>Child</Type>
    </IsSMA>
    <IsCashAccount>false</IsCashAccount>
    <IsSubjectToCGT>true</IsSubjectToCGT>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</InvestmentHolding>
<InvestmentHolding>
    <AccountId>900004859</AccountId>
    <InvestmentCode>WBC</InvestmentCode>
    <Exchange>ASX</Exchange>
    <HoldingId>10983135</HoldingId>
    <IsSMA>
        <Id>900004859.04</Id>
        <Type>Child</Type>
    </IsSMA>
    <IsCashAccount>false</IsCashAccount>
    <IsSubjectToCGT>true</IsSubjectToCGT>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</InvestmentHolding>
<InvestmentHolding>
    <AccountId>900004859</AccountId>
    <InvestmentCode>ALD</InvestmentCode>
    <Exchange>ASX</Exchange>
    <HoldingId>11110905</HoldingId>
    <IsSMA>
        <Id>900004859.04</Id>
        <Type>Child</Type>
    </IsSMA>
    <IsCashAccount>false</IsCashAccount>
    <IsSubjectToCGT>true</IsSubjectToCGT>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</InvestmentHolding>
<InvestmentHolding>
    <AccountId>900004859</AccountId>
    <InvestmentCode>JBH</InvestmentCode>
    <Exchange>ASX</Exchange>
    <HoldingId>11502127</HoldingId>
    <IsSMA>
        <Id>900004859.04</Id>
        <Type>Child</Type>
    </IsSMA>
    <IsCashAccount>false</IsCashAccount>
    <IsSubjectToCGT>true</IsSubjectToCGT>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</InvestmentHolding>
<InvestmentHolding>
    <AccountId>900004859</AccountId>
    <InvestmentCode>CCL</InvestmentCode>
    <Exchange>ASX</Exchange>
    <HoldingId>13260065</HoldingId>
    <IsSMA>
        <Id>900004859.04</Id>
        <Type>Child</Type>
    </IsSMA>
    <IsCashAccount>false</IsCashAccount>
    <IsSubjectToCGT>true</IsSubjectToCGT>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</InvestmentHolding>
<InvestmentHolding>
    <AccountId>900004859</AccountId>
    <InvestmentCode>WFS3783AU</InvestmentCode>
    <Exchange>UNL</Exchange>
    <HoldingId>CLT.15468.MP.3</HoldingId>
    <IsSMA>
        <Id>900004859.03</Id>
        <Type>Parent</Type>
    </IsSMA>
    <IsCashAccount>false</IsCashAccount>
    <IsSubjectToCGT>false</IsSubjectToCGT>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</InvestmentHolding>
<InvestmentHolding>
    <AccountId>900004859</AccountId>
    <InvestmentCode>PIM0941AU</InvestmentCode>
    <Exchange>FND</Exchange>
    <HoldingId>13797105</HoldingId>
    <IsSMA>
        <Id>900004859.03</Id>
        <Type>Child</Type>
    </IsSMA>
    <IsCashAccount>false</IsCashAccount>
    <IsSubjectToCGT>true</IsSubjectToCGT>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</InvestmentHolding>
<InvestmentHolding>
    <AccountId>900004859</AccountId>
    <InvestmentCode>BHP</InvestmentCode>
    <Exchange>ASX</Exchange>
    <HoldingId>10983149</HoldingId>
    <IsSMA>
        <Id>900004859.04</Id>
        <Type>Child</Type>
    </IsSMA>
    <IsCashAccount>false</IsCashAccount>
    <IsSubjectToCGT>true</IsSubjectToCGT>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</InvestmentHolding>
```

I'm trying to match nodes //IsSMA/Id with the //IsSMA/Id of the Parent(//SMAId/Type='Parent') and return //InvestmentCode for the Parent for all rows.
This is my xslt;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text" />


<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>


<!--  Create Header Record  -->
<xsl:template match="xxxxx">
<!-- Some other xslt here to extract header info -->
    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="InvestmentHolding" />      
         
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="SMAId" match="InvestmentHolding" use="HoldingId" />
<xsl:key name="SMA_ID" match="InvestmentHolding" use="IsSMA/Id" />

<!--  Extract Holding and Product Details combined -->
<xsl:template match="InvestmentHolding">
    
    <xsl:text>"HoldingProduct"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>,"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="AccountId" />
    <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="InvestmentCode" />
    <xsl:text>","</xsl:text>
    <!--  Get the SMA Id and use this to get the Parent InvestmentCode --> 
    <xsl:variable name="SMA" select="key('SMAId', HoldingId)/IsSMA/Id" />
    <xsl:value-of select="key('SMA_ID', $SMA)/InvestmentCode" />
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text> 
    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the result;

```
"Header","V4.2"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","CASH",""
"HoldingProduct","900004859","ALX","ALX"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","AMC","ALX"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","MTS","ALX"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","NAB",""
"HoldingProduct","900004859","QBE","ALX"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","BTFG.SU.6M.MAT",""
"HoldingProduct","900004859","MPCASH","MPCASH"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","BGL0008AU","MPCASH"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","BGL0044AU","MPCASH"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","BGL0108AU","MPCASH"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","HOW0098AU","MPCASH"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","SSB4647AU","MPCASH"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","WBC","ALX"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","ALD","ALX"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","JBH","ALX"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","CCL","ALX"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","WFS3783AU","MPCASH"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","PIM0941AU","MPCASH"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","BHP","ALX"
```

This is the desired result;

```
"Header","V4.2"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","CASH",""
"HoldingProduct","900004859","ALX","WFS3783AU"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","AMC","WFS3783AU"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","MTS","WFS3783AU"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","NAB",""
"HoldingProduct","900004859","QBE","WFS3783AU"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","BTFG.SU.6M.MAT",""
"HoldingProduct","900004859","MPCASH","WFS3783AU"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","BGL0008AU","WFS3783AU"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","BGL0044AU","WFS3783AU"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","BGL0108AU","WFS3783AU"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","HOW0098AU","WFS3783AU"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","SSB4647AU","WFS3783AU"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","WBC","WFS3783AU"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","ALD","WFS3783AU"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","JBH","WFS3783AU"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","CCL","WFS3783AU"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","WFS3783AU",""
"HoldingProduct","900004859","PIM0941AU","WFS3783AU"
"HoldingProduct","900004859","BHP","WFS3783AU"
```

The select of the Investment code seems to pick up the 1st instance and repeat for each row. I'm not sure how to match on the IsSMA/Type element to get the desired result of WFS3783AU (being the Parent IsSMA/Type) for each row where there is an IsSMA/Id.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It would help us understand the problem if you simplified the data to something short. Perhaps restricting the key to `<xsl:key name="SMA_ID" match="InvestmentHolding[IsSMA/Type = 'Parent']" use="IsSMA/Id"/>` gives you the right cross-reference for `key('SMA_ID', $SMA)` but I haven't been able to identify the relationships.

Comment: Thanks Martin Honnen that change did the trick.